# Why doesn't my 301 redirect work in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have the following server block and I'm trying to do a 301 redirect so www.realestatelicensebystate.com goes to http://realestatelicensebystate.com for SEO purposes.  Problem is, after I put the line in there, I'm getting the generic "Welcome to nginx" screen.  Here is the code:

```
    server {
            listen   80;
            server_name www.realestatelicensebystate.com;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://realestatelicensebystate.com/$1 permanent;
            access_log /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/logs/access.log;
            error_log /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/logs/error.log;
            location / {
                    root   /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/public_html;
                    index index.html index.htm index.php;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    #fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
    }
```

Anything stand out or is there anything I should be doing better?  I'm brand new to nginx and learning.

Comment: It is easier to use [return](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). Check the section adding and removing www.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why you are getting default nginx page is here:

```
server_name www.realestatelicensebystate.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://realestatelicensebystate.com/$1 permanent;
```

Your server is listening for name www.realestatelicensebystate.com and you are redirecting to realestatelicensebystate.com.

You need to create either another vhost config or new server block for your new name.

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name www.realestatelicensebystate.com;
            rewrite ^ http://realestatelicensebystate.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
            listen   80;
            server_name realestatelicensebystate.com;

            access_log /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/logs/access.log;
            error_log /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/logs/error.log;
            location / {
                    root   /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/public_html;
                    index index.html index.htm index.php;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    #fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/realestatelicensebystate.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
    }
```